# Задать направление при сортировке повторным нажатием на блок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как можно отловить повторное нажатие на тот же блок для сортировки в обратном порядке? Если нажать на блок, то оно сортирует по убыванию, повторное нажатие должно менять направление по возврастанию, если же выбран другой блок, то снова же по убыванию.

```js
$('.sorted').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
    <div class="sorted">id</div> 
    <div class="sorted">phone</div> 
    <div class="sorted">index</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: а что тут сортируется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.sorted').click(function(){
  $(this).data("direction", ($(this).data("direction") != "DESC")? "DESC" : "ASC");
  console.log("Sort by", $(this).text(), $(this).data("direction"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
    <div class="sorted">id</div> 
    <div class="sorted">phone</div> 
    <div class="sorted">index</div> 
</div>
```